# Duplicated WordPress Site STILL Linked to Old Site

Tags: backup, duplicates

I have WordPress site 1 on domain1.com.

I copied WordPress site 1 to WordPress site 2 on domain2.com (database and files).

Both WordPress sites have their independent database names/usernames/passwords and separate FTP credentials/directories.

Both WordPress sites are on the same server (localhost).

When I delete a plugin/theme from WordPress site 2, that plugin/theme also gets deleted from WordPress site 1 (and vice versa)! Likewise, when I install a new plugin/theme on one of the sites, it also gets installed on the other site!

However, if I  activate a plugin/theme on one site, it does not get activated on the other site. Also, if I add/delete a post/page/media file from one site, it does not get added/deleted to the other site.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? I made sure there are no references in database 2 to database 1, and I even hardcoded the siteurl into wp-config.php

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

I'm still having this problem after three hours of deleting the database/files and re-uploading them. I even tried creating WordPress site 2 on entirely different FTP directories with new credentials (and likewise a new database and credentials) to no avail!

EDIT:

It gets even crazier. I completely deleted WordPress site 2's database and all files. I then did a completely NEW WordPress install, and when I click on Plugins, I see all the plugins that are on WordPress site 1 (likewise for themes)! The problem somehow still exists! Now I am completely stumped.

I'm on an Ubuntu server running Nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was the culprit after all. I searched through all my files for domain1.com and sure enough on lines 7/8 of wp-config.php, I found these lines (which I completely forgot about):

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://domain1.com/customlogin' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/user/domain1.com/customlogin' );
```

Answer (score 0):

i also faced this issue, but i just download my database and ( find and replace url using sumblime text 3 ) everything work fine now, if you use

```
define('WP_HOME','http://domain.com/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://domain.com/');
```

this is okey, but not okey with SEO i think.

otherwise if your both sites are online, you can use **wp db migrate** wordpress plugin, its very usefull.